# How can I pass credentials for running terraform import?

Tags: terraform

That's a piece of my tf configuration:

```
resource "custom_bar" "orders" {
  name = "Bar Orders"
}
```

After creating a resource above using UI I run:

```
terraform import custom_bar.orders e-1234
```

but run into auth issues:

```
Error: could not find credentials block
```

even though I set it to optional in my schema. Anyway, in order to send a read requests for this resource terraform needs to set

```
credentials {
    key = "..."
    secret = "..."
  }
```

block that I'd typically specify in config manually:

```
resource "custom_bar" "tf_orders" {
  name = "TF Managed Bar Orders"

  credentials {
    key = "my-key"
    secret = "my-secret"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

**upd**: I do have a credentials for provider as well but I do need an additional set of creds on a per `custom_bar` resource basis (i.e., every instance of custom_bar will have their own key:secret pair if that makes sense which is why setting those in env vars is not very convenient too since I might have like 5 custom_bar resource instances).

**upd2**: here's a full definition of `custom_bar` resource:

```
// full schema for custom_bar resource
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "name": {
        Type:     schema.TypeString,
        Required: true,
        ForceNew: true,
    },
    "description": {
        Type:     schema.TypeString,
        Optional: true,
        ForceNew: true,
    },
    "TTL": {
        Type:     schema.TypeInt,
        Optional: true,
        ForceNew: true,
    },
    paramCredentials: credentialsSchema(),
},


...

func credentialsSchema() *schema.Schema {
    return &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeSet,
        Required: true,
        MinItems: 1,
        MaxItems: 1,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                paramKey: {
                    Type:        schema.TypeString,
                    Required:    true,
                    Description: "key",
                    Sensitive:   true,
                },
                paramSecret: {
                    Type:        schema.TypeString,
                    Required:    true,
                    Description: "secret",
                    Sensitive:   true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a custom terraform provider you are creating? You would typically set the credentials in a `provider` block, not a `resource` block. Or set them as environment variables.

Comment: It's a custom provider, yes. I do have a creds for provider but I do need an additional set of creds on a per custom_bar resouce basis (i.e., every instance of custom_bar will have their own key:secret pair if that makes sense which is why setting those in env vars is not very convenient too since I might have like 5 custom_bar resource instances).

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to answer your question without seeing the code, or documentation for this custom provider.

Comment: @MarkB sure, would you like to see the code for schema of that resource? I can easily edit it tbh so it's not set. It's rather a design question I guess.

Comment: *edit the schema of this resource, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to pass creds on a per resource basis while saving the ability to import it.

Comment: Where is the full definition of `custom_bar`?

Comment: @Marcin added the full definition of `custom_bar` to the question.

Comment: @MarkB added the full definition of `custom_bar` to the question.